# OpenCV + Numpy Script

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

The issue I'm having is that the two scripts below are both outputting this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAjqm.png

```
TypeError: FeatureDetector.detect() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

which I can avoid in the script 2 below by deleting:

```
useProvidedKeypoints = False
```

from the end of

```
kp, descritors = surf.detect(imgg,None,useProvidedKeypoints = False)
```

which leads to this error in the 2nd script :https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyMTF.png

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

And this error in the first script: i.imgur.com/UVzNvP1.png (2 link limit add manually)

```
TypeError: trainData data type = 17 is not supported
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and the main thing I want to come out of this is with a script I can tweak and edit till I understand the functions involved slightly better.

Summary; I'm not really sure why `kp, descritors = surf.detect(imgg,None,useProvidedKeypoints = False)` is telling me there too many arguments because the person who helped me write this seemed to think this should work.

## 1

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img =cv2.imread('win18.jpg')

imgg =cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

surf = cv2.SURF()
kp, descritors = surf.detect(imgg,None,useProvidedKeypoints = False)


samples = np.array(descritors)
responses = np.arange(len(kp),dtype = np.float32)


knn = cv2.KNearest()
knn.train(samples,responses)


template = cv2.imread('win17.jpg')
templateg= cv2.cvtColor(template,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
keys,desc = surf.detect(templateg,None,useProvidedKeypoints = False)


for h,des in enumerate(desc):
    des = np.array(des,np.float32).reshape((1,128))
    retval, results, neigh_resp, dists = knn.find_nearest(des,1)
    res,dist =  int(results[0][0]),dists[0][0]


    if dist<0.1: 
        color = (0,0,255)
    else: 
        print dist
        color = (255,0,0)


    x,y = kp[res].pt
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    cv2.circle(img,center,2,color,-1)

    x,y = keys[h].pt
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    cv2.circle(template,center,2,color,-1)


cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.imshow('tm',template)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

## 2

```
import cv2
import numpy

opencv_haystack =cv2.imread('win12.jpg')
opencv_needle =cv2.imread('win1.jpg')

ngrey = cv2.cvtColor(opencv_needle, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hgrey = cv2.cvtColor(opencv_haystack, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


hessian_threshold = 85
detector = cv2.SURF(hessian_threshold)
(hkeypoints, hdescriptors) = detector.detect(hgrey, None, useProvidedKeypoints = False)
(nkeypoints, ndescriptors) = detector.detect(ngrey, None, useProvidedKeypoints = False)


rowsize = len(hdescriptors) / len(hkeypoints)
if rowsize > 1:
    hrows = numpy.array(hdescriptors, dtype = numpy.float32).reshape((-1, rowsize))
    nrows = numpy.array(ndescriptors, dtype = numpy.float32).reshape((-1, rowsize))

else:
    hrows = numpy.array(hdescriptors, dtype = numpy.float32)
    nrows = numpy.array(ndescriptors, dtype = numpy.float32)
    rowsize = len(hrows[0])


samples = hrows
responses = numpy.arange(len(hkeypoints), dtype = numpy.float32)

knn = cv2.KNearest()
knn.train(samples,responses)



    if dist < 0.1:

        color = (0, 0, 255)
    else:

        color = (255, 0, 0)

    x,y = hkeypoints[res].pt
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    cv2.circle(opencv_haystack,center,2,color,-1)

    x,y = nkeypoints[i].pt
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    cv2.circle(opencv_needle,center,2,color,-1)

cv2.imshow('haystack',opencv_haystack)
cv2.imshow('needle',opencv_needle)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You may learn something by making this into an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) - make the script as short as possible, then start adding things back until you figure out why the error appears.

Comment: Also, in the future, you generally don't need to include screenshots of your IDE with the error showing - simply providing the code and the error message is usually sufficient. It might also be helpful to post the full traceback that's produced when the error occurs

Comment: Hey thank's for the advice, I've been trying to turn this into a SSCCE but I'm having trouble dividing the functions and such. My main goal is to detect if a picture is on screen and click it, i know how to setup clicks and such but I'm having a hard time creating my SSCCE for image detection. Could you help by shortening this script ?

Comment: Also what do you think I should be googling to find the documentation for these modules in particular. (OpenCv, numpy, Pillow)

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a debugging service, and I'm just trying to help in bits of time off during my day, so I don't have time to shorten the script for you. Anyways, the best way to learn is to do it yourself. Usually, googling the error message is a good start, and you should also read the specific documentation for the methods you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I know it's late but for the ones still facing the problem, try replacing `detect()` with `detectAndCompute()`.

I got the error removed this way.

Answer (score 0):

when in doubt, ...

```
>>> s = cv2.SURF()
>>> help(s.detect)
Help on built-in function detect:

detect(...)
    detect(image[, mask]) -> keypoints
```

so, your assumptions about the args to SURF.detect() were quite off.

Comment: So there should be 3 arg then? or is there actually an extra one that I should remove?

Comment: one of us 3 can't count

Comment: sorry for pulling your leg, but it takes either an image only , or an image and a mask, and returns keypoints.

Comment: Haha good thing i came back late :P, Ok well this will help alot. Right now I'm taking darthbith's advice and trying to create a SSCCE by breaking down the script into functions and looking them up individually! Ill get it, thanks again!